# Help me insert entries into a C++ std map

Tags: c++, dictionary

```
map<int, BasicBlock*> basicBlocks; // in my header file
basicBlocks.insert(std::pair<int, BasicBlock*>(pc, bb));
```

where pc is an integer and bb is a BasicBlock: (earlier)

```
BasicBlock *bb = new BasicBlock(pc);
```

that is from earlier in the code.

I get this error: error C2664: 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::pair(const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'BasicBlock *' to 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &'

```
Why would it even need to convert the parameter? 



    void ConstantPoolParser::createBasicBlocks(Method* method)
    {
    cout << "Creating basic block's in method: " << method->getName() << endl;
    char* bytecode = method->getBytecode();
    int bytecodeLength = method->getBytecodeLength();
    int pc = 0;
    basicBlocks.insert(new BasicBlock(pc));

    for(pc = 0; pc < bytecodeLength; pc++)
    {
        int opcode = bytecode[pc] & 0xFF;
        switch(opcode)
        {
            case IF_ICMPEQ: // 159 (0x9f) eq
            case IF_ICMPNE: // 160 (0xa0) ne
            case IF_ICMPLT: // 161 (0xa1) lt
            case IF_ICMPGE: // 162 (0xa2) ge
            case IF_ICMPGT: // 163 (0xa3) gt
            case IF_ICMPLE: // 164 (0xa4) le
            case GOTO: // 167 (0xa7) goto
            {
                int branchbyte1 = bytecode[pc+1] & 0xFF;
                int branchbyte2 = bytecode[pc+2] & 0xFF;
                int branchTarget =  branchbyte1 << 8 | branchbyte2 + pc; //(branchbyte1 << 8) | branchbyte2
                cout << "we got into a branch case! " << opcode << " Branch target: " << branchTarget << endl;

                basicBlocks.insert( std::pair<int, BasicBlock*>(pc, new BasicBlock(pc)) );
                basicBlocks.insert( std::pair<int, BasicBlock*>(branchTarget, new BasicBlock(branchTarget)) );

                pc+=2; // loop will add 1 to pc
                break;
            }
        }//end switch
    }// end for
}
```

Comment: What is `pc`?  Can you give a bit more pretty source code?

Comment: This error does not make sense. Where is pc defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the line:

```
basicBlocks.insert(new BasicBlock(pc));
```

This is trying to insert a `BasicBlock*` into the map, not a pair.  Did you mean:

```
basicBlocks.insert(std::make_pair(pc, new BasicBlock(pc)) );
```

Comment: You win. I was looking at the wrong section. I'm used to easy debugging of java, c++ never tells me the line of things that are wrong.

Comment: @Dave: What compiler/environment are you using that it doesn't give you line numbers?

Comment: I'm in Visual Studio 2010, and for some reason for this bug it didn't give a line number. Most bugs it does however in the build results.

Answer (score 2):

You can also just write:

```
basicBlocks[pc] = bb;
```

However, whatever method you use, you need to be sure that you only have one entry for each value of pc. If you need multiple entries, you multimap<>.